# gdal translate Error 6 Too many command options

Tags: command-line

I use the following command and gets the error "too many command options"

```
gdal_translate -of AAIGrid –tr 10 10 alle_mine_tif_filer.vrt min_nu_samlede_10km_fil.asc
```

Can you help me?

Comment: The command looks good. Make sure that you don't have any spaces in the parameters, for example `alle mine_tif_filer.vrt` triggers that error.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is due to the use of an "En Dash" [character](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+2013) instead of an "Hyphen-Minus" [character](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+002d) for the "-tr" option.

The following command should work:

```
gdal_translate -of AAIGrid -tr 10 10 alle_mine_tif_filer.vrt min_nu_samlede_10km_fil.asc
```

Comment: Good catch! But it may depend on the locale, on my computer copy-paste from the question worked well.